# AWS Step Functions SDK: State type `Choice` does not support method `next`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a workflow with a choice state that checks for a certain variable and that kicks off the previous step again if the condition was met, or move to the next step if not.

```
import stepfunctions

first_job = stepfunctions.steps.Pass('First job')
second_job = stepfunctions.steps.Pass('Second job')

check = stepfunctions.steps.Choice('Check first job')
check.add_choice(
    rule=stepfunctions.steps.ChoiceRule.BooleanEquals(
        variable='$run_me_again',
        value=True
    ),
    next_step=first_job
)
check.default_choice(second_job) # This could be set automatically

chain = stepfunctions.steps.Chain([first_job, check, second_job])
```

The last line wants to chain the different steps so that we can convert it to a workflow but this line raises an error:

```
ValueError: ... , State type `Choice` does not support method `next`.
```

Why does this raise an error? it makes sense to have downstream tasks after a choice state.

I got the example from [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-step-functions-data-science-sdk-python/issues/31)

Answer (score 1):

Choice states don't support the End field. In addition, they use Next only inside their Choices field.

Also you can use "Default": The name of the state to transition to if none of the transitions in Choices is taken.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html